# Is there a way to use FluentValidation with EntityFramework codefirst in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, fluentvalidation

I am learning and working on CQRS with MediatR. It gives an oppurtunity to have clean architecture.

So to put all my validation out of my UI I try to use FluentValidation (https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation).

But I could not find the way to use it with Entity Framework migrations in documents or on google.

Is there a way?

Comment: You want to use it with *migrations?*  How would that even work?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I can not use it with Migrations I need to write Validation rules for migrations with DataAnnotuations or FluentAPI. And Rewrite them for my entities with FluentValidation and that is duplicate code. I want to write  Validation Rules one time for each Entity so I can use it in entire project.

Comment: If you use DataAnnotuations why would you have to rewrite those as FluentValidation?

Comment: you can refer to this popular project that does fulentvalidation and ef in a clean approach. https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation
but this seems to do it seperatly

Answer (score 1):

Validations that you write in FluentValidation are just for client-side, not server-side validations, and validations you write in Fluent-API are just for defining database tables constraints.

The idea of using Fluent-API + Fluent-Validation instead of DataAnnotations is that you separated Client-Side Validation and Server-Side table constraints.

[This video](http://kutt.it/cav) will also help you to get the idea.

Comment: I believe OP wants to extract some of the medata from DbContext.Model, e.g. (MaxLength, Required) and generate validation rules based on them without writing them manually.

Comment: I used FluentValidation for client and server classes. They act as good Domain Invariants on entities.